# Installing redhat-lsb on CentOS 7 on an offline machine

Tags: linux, perl, package, redhat

I'm trying to install Hortonworks on my CentOS 7 machine which does not have access to the internet. The installation of Hortonworks has failed because package redhat-lsb has not been installed on the machine. I'm trying to install the package and it comes with certain dependencies.

It first asks for: `perl(ExtUtils::MakeMaker)`
When I try to install that one it's asking for: `perl(ExtUtils::Installed)`
And when I try to install that one it's asking for: `perl(ExtUtils::MakeMaker)`

So I'm caught in a loop and I can't find with packages I'm missing before I'm able to install `perl(ExtUtils::MakeMaker)`.

I search for packages on rpmfind.net.
Any ideas or tips to help me further? Not sure if these questions are allowed because it does not have to do with programming, please let me know if that is the case.

Comment: Try `$ yum install perl-devel perl-CPAN`

Comment: You need to install them simultaneously.

Comment: Thank you, installing simultaneously did the trick!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I see It looks like you don't have Perl installed,a simple way to check it is using the following command:

*perl -v*

Case it shows you an errors download and install the last version of Perl.

If you already have it installed I would recommend you install these basics packages:

- perl-devel
- perl-core
- perl-Module-CoreList
- perl-CPAN (If you don't have acess to the internet it will not be that useful )

Probably it will helps you solve most part of the dependencies you have for now.